# How can I throw a duplicate key exception?

Tags: hazelcast

I am using hz 3.10.1 version. I would like to know will hazelcast throw a duplicate key exception when multiple threads try to insert the same key? Our scenario is only allowed 1 key to insert.

Comment: very simple to test for yourself - I tried it and it did not throw any exception. (v 3.10.3)

Comment: @user1373164 ya, I know, but I think hz should prevent duplicate key. Do you know any way we can achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

Hazelcast maps are thread safe by design, alike to java COncurrentHashmap in that sense. So there will be no exception and both put operations will happen one after another.

OTOH, if you want to ensure to insert each key only once, maybe you can use putIfAbsent method of Hazelcast map.

Comment: hi, what about if my application host on two servers, both receive the same key, will putIfAbsent still thread safe?

Comment: yes sure, hazelcast distributes keys to members so both operation will go to the member which owns that key. That member will handle all the incoming operations for that key.